# Как авторизоваться на сайте средствами Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi

**Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста.**

Не могу зарегистрироваться на сайте программно. 
Пробовал  2 методами - не получилось.

```
    html_tag:=WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.item(0).elements;
 for i:=0 to (html_tag.length-1) do
 begin
 if (html_tag.item(i).name='user') then
 html_tag.item(i).value:='*********';

 if (html_tag.item(i).name='pswd') then
 html_tag.item(i).value:='***********' ;

 if (html_tag.item(i).tagname = 'button') and
(html_tag.item(i).type = 'submit') then
html_tag.item(i).click;
```

2 способ методом `POST`. Тоже ошибку выдала.
Вот код:

```
var
  LoginInfo: TStringList;
  Response: TStringStream;
begin
  try
    LoginInfo := TStringList.Create;
    Response := TStringStream.Create('');
    LoginInfo.Add('username=MyName');
    LoginInfo.Add('password=MyPass');
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://mywebsite.xxx/login.php',LoginInfo,Response);
    Showmessage(Response.DataString);
  finally
    begin
      Response.Free;
      LoginInfo.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Вот то, что отловил `HTTP Analyzer`:

```
midAuth               0,1         
user                  ***********  
pswd                 ***********    
GUID1801934821098200

https://*************:8443/bgbilling/webexecuter
```

А вот код, по которому нужна авторизация.

```
<form action="webexecuter" method="post">
  <input value="0,1" name="midAuth" type="hidden">
  <table class="filter">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100" align="left">Номер договора или логин:</td>
        <td>
          <input class="inputLogin" size="15" name="user" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100" align="left">Пароль:</td>
        <td>
          <input class="inputPassword" size="15" name="pswd" type="password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
          <input id="GUID1801934821098225" name="GUID1801934821098225" type="hidden">
          <button onclick="jQuery('#GUID1801934821098225')[0].form.submit()" type="submit" class="gradbtn blue" id="">Вход</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
          <a style="font-size: x-small" href="pubexecuter?action=PasswordForgot&module=admin">Забыли пароль?</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в `HTML` форме поле для ввода пароля называется `pswd (name="pswd")`, а в своем коде Вы используете `password`.

```
<input class="inputPassword" size="15" name="pswd" type="password">
```

Comment: Это я скопировал из шаблона в кода  так (name="pswd") и вводил.

Comment: при использовании IdHTTP1 там есть возможность настройки кукисов? кстати, по какому принципу поле GUID*** выводится? Может быть оно постоянно разное, и поэтому не происходит авторизации?

Answer (score 0):

```
   HTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   HTTP.Request.Authentication.Free;
   HTTP.Request.Authentication:= IdAuthentication.TIdBasicAuthentication.create;
   HTTP.Request.Authentication.Username:='user';
   HTTP.Request.Authentication.Password:='pass';
   HTTP.Post('http://mysite.com','здесь данные&которые&надо&передать');
```

Comment: Спасибо я проверю на счет GUID